# I am trying to make a function that returns a list of a specific length and has repetitions of one of the values

Tags: python, list

What I'm trying to get, should look like this:

```
myList = makeList ('r', 6)

['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']
```

First value is what should be returned, second is the amount of times it should be returned.

What I tried is:

```
def myList():
    a = raw_input("Enter a value: ")
    b = raw_input("How many %s's would you like to see?: " % a)
    b = a.count(a)

    if b.isdigit():  
        return a * int(b)
```

Comment: `def makeList (v, c): return [v for _ in range(c)]`

Comment: it's close, but what is the `b = a.count(a)` supposed to do?

Comment: It was my attempt to count the characters in a. I'm very knew to this, I apologize.

Comment: no problem... it actually counts the times that a appears in a, which is always 1. you want `len(a)` for the number of characters - which is still not what you wanted - your instinct about just using `int(b)` was better. if you leave that line out, and replace `a * int(b)` with `[a] * int(b)`, then your existing version will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable objects in Python. So, it is safer to create multiple instances of the same string with `*` operator, like this

```
def makeList(char, count):
    return [char] * count

print makeList("r", 6)    # ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']
print makeList("rr", 6)   # ['rr', 'rr', 'rr', 'rr', 'rr', 'rr']
```

Comment: can we change it to lambda F

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan If this function is used multiple times, it is better to create it with `def`

Comment: I think not multiple time but multiple places. in list-compression, map lambda function called many times Hence I think just `makeList = lambda a, b: [a] * b` is done

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan If they are used once and thrown away, it makes sense, like in a map. But not a convenient function like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` to duplicate a list:

```
>>> ['r'] * 6
['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']
```

Or a string:

```
>>> 'r' * 6
'rrrrrr'
>>> list('r' * 6)
['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a list and then specify the number of times:

```
def makeList(char,count):
    return [char]*count

print makeList("r",6)
```